# Query across multiple tables and rows/columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, dml

I am having an issue with an SQL database I am setting up using Oracle 11g express edition. I am wanting to be able to run a SELECT query in which for each customer, I want to show the customer’s number and the sum of all that customer’s credit transaction (transactions with a type of ‘C’) amounts for accounts that have an open status.

Problem...I have looked at the different types of Query commands and I am completely lost as to how I should format this command in the simplest terms. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my table formatting:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer_DML

  CustomerNumber CHAR(12) CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY, 

  SSN CHAR(9) CONSTRAINT customer_uq_ssn UNIQUE,

  FirstName VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT customer_nn_fname NOT NULL,

  LastName VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT customer_nn_lname NOT NULL,

  Telephone CHAR(10),

  DateOfBirth DATE
);



CREATE TABLE Account_DML (

  AccountNumber CHAR(15) CONSTRAINT account_pk PRIMARY KEY,

  Type CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT account_ck_type CHECK (Type IN ('S','C')),

  DateCreated DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE CONSTRAINT account_nn_datecreated NOT NULL,

  Status VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT account_nn_status NOT NULL,

  Customer CHAR(12) CONSTRAINT account_fk_customer REFERENCES 
Customer_DML(CustomerNumber)

ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE Transaction_DML (

  TransactionNumber CHAR(15) CONSTRAINT transaction_pk PRIMARY KEY,

  Type CHAR(1) CONSTRAINT transaction_ck_type CHECK (Type IN ('D','C')),

  Amount Number(10,2) CONSTRAINT transaction_nn_amount NOT NULL,

  Account CHAR(15) CONSTRAINT transaction_fk_account REFERENCES Account_DML(AccountNumber)

ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

What I have so far is along these lines:

```
SELECT c.CustomerNumber,
t.SUM(Amount) AS SumAmt
FROM Customer_DML c, Account_DML a
ON c.CustomerNumber = a.Customer
JOIN Transaction_DML t
ON a.Customer = a.AccountNumber
```

But I have a feeling that I am really off base with this.

Any Hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info I would be happy to give what I can.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You are also missing a `GROUP BY`, so I think you mean:

```
SELECT a.Customer as CustomerNumber, SUM(t.Amount) AS SumAmt
FROM Account_DML a 
JOIN Transaction_DML t
     ON t.Account = a.AccountNumber
GROUP BY a.Customer;
```

You do not need to join to the customer table, because the `Account` table has the customer number needed for the aggregation.

Comment: When you are using the "Account table" do you mean Account_DML or the Account column? I tried pasting this into my command line and I am getting several errors.

Comment: And when I am correcting this to be "Account_DML" I am getting an error at line 5 where it says "C"."Customer": invalid identifier.

Comment: I submitted an edit with corrections. Try changing c.Customer to a.Customer in both the select and the group by.

Comment: It is giving me an error: FROM Account a JOIN ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. I did implement the changes you suggested though. By "Account" on line 2 did you mean "Account_DML"?

Comment: Also I need to only sum the amounts that are of Type C in the Transaction_DML table. Any other type should not be added. The 2 types being 'D' and 'C'. BTW thank you all for your help so far.

Comment: I guess I will also point out that I do not want any accounts with the Status of 'Closed' to show up in the query either, So I guess to summarize: Only Amounts with Type C should be Summed and shown, Accounts with Status Closed should not be shown, show the Sum of these amounts and show the Open accounts that use Type C.